# What is the difference between the NC14 and the LA80?

Tags: planetside-2

Both rifles have the exact same stats and seem to behave the exact same way, so what exactly is the difference?

[image: NC14 Bolt Driver]
[image: LA80]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LA80 has less bullet drop, which means it is easier to score long range headshots.